# JMeter: Getting Response 'Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue'

Tags: jmeter

A JMeter Script is working fine in **my Local Machine** (means in a different network) but the same script is failing in different network (VDI) with error ***'Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue'*** ('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden').

There is no issue of firewall in VDI machine. Seems need to add some header/some manager to enable JavaScript and cookie in VDI machine.

Added screenshot for details:

[image: Header Manager]
[image: Response Body]
[image: Response Header]

Please help me to understand , what exactly I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which says:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you cannot "enable" JavaScript unless you switch to a real browser via i.e. [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin.

The fact that script works on one machine and doesn't work on another most probably means missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) like you recorded a hard-coded parameter which is fine for one machine and isn't suitable for another. So double check your request for any suspicious dynamic values and correlate them and it should resolve your issue.

Comparing request data from "local" and "VDI" could also help, take a look at request URL, body and headers using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

Comment: Hello Dmitri, 
I have check in both environments and found the Request header and Body are same and no Correlation we have used in our Script . Details in below Picture

Comment: This website is behind [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/) therefore you won't be able to test using JMeter and even if you will use WebDriver Sampler you won't get valid results because cloudflare can also act as a DDoS attacks protection service.  You should [exclude any 3rd-party resources](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) and turn off external services like 2FA or cloudflare for the load test.

Comment: You don't need to "update" me, comments section is not designed for that so please don't do it.